# How to make a cat's perspective exciting?

Tags: fiction, characters, perspective

I'm writing an article about a cat saving a three-year-old girl's life. What tools or techniques can I use to keep the reader interested?

Comment: Hi Gabriella! Welcome to Writers.SE! :) A couple of questions to help you get answers: (A) Are you wondering if _writing from a cat's perspective_ is possible, or if _a cat saving a child_ is possible? (B) Is there anything holding you back? Are you running into any problems? Have you tried writing a bit, and seeing how it goes?

Comment: We actually try to avoid questions about what, specifically, you should or shouldn't write -- so your question might be closed. But we have a general-purpose post [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/25819/writing-a-novel-can-i-do-this-or-that) that you might find helpful! :D

Comment: Is this fiction? If you're creating a fictive perspective of the cat's world, then there are already some great answer on 'writing from a cat's perspective" here: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/29848/how-to-write-from-a-cats-perspective

Comment: The Book of Night With Moon.

Comment: Here is what another author did with this concept. Probably not applicable to your question, but fun. https://faculty.uca.edu/rnovy/Leiber--SpaceTime%20for%20Springers.htm

Answer (score 5):

There is many things you can do to make a story through a cat's perspective compelling. There is great potential for witty moments, thrilling moments, interesting moments and even heartwarming moments. I say "even", because cats are the pet equivalent of psychopaths (or sociopaths). They care about themselves, as is their nature, shaped by evolution, since they do not need to care for other individuals. It would be obstructional for them to care. They're not flock animals, therefore not social animals, hence their natural lack of empathy.

This lack of empathy is an example of a cat trait that you can either adhere to, or subvert. You could make your cat unique in the way that it is selfless (as Sriram said). It does save a child's life after all. But then again, this could be because of self-centered motivations, or even by accident. What I really meant with this point is that you should read up on the animal. Know its behaviour and quirks, because that is the only way you can truly write from its perspective. I find stories with elements centered in truth much more compelling. Of course, it would be unrealistic to try to make a story like this realistic. —It doesn't need to be either.

As I mentioned earlier, the potential for humour, thrill and curiosity is unending. The humour can come from the cat's selfish, nonchalant and apathetic outlook on life and the people around it. Thrill can come from the many dangers a cat must endure. If in the city, there's a lot of scary stuff creeping in alleyways, and cars zooming past on the streets. If on the countryside, there's lots of scary animals that can harm your cat, e.g. eagles, badgers, coyotes and not limited to the countryside, **humans**.

Cats are also naturally curious, as it is beneficial to their opportunistic lifestyle. Whenever a situation calls out the curiosity in the cat MC, you have endless possibilities for mystery, curiosity (within the reader), anticipation, etc.

Comment: Adding onto this, the Warriors book series by Erin Hunter are stories about cats.

Comment: Your answer somewhat makes me think of Forrest Gump, where the main character's line of thinking is vastly different from the reality as perceived by the "normal" (very much mind those quotes) people (and by extension the viewer). Similarly, you can make an enjoyable plotline from following the cat's flawed interpretation, as long as it's an interesting twist on what is "really" happening.

Answer (score 2):

Catacylism and catastrophic story will set forward when you categorise your cat story. Cast the cat as a catch 22. Load the story gently and meld the characters. The mostly useful part in this story line is selfless cat life. It grows near owner and serves the master when it's the highest need. Non fiction would have been my choice if I was it's writer. Take a leap and act like a cat, start.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a story about a cat as the main character, and it was pretty hard, in my opinion.

My tips:

1. Try and see through the cat's perspective. It may be hard, but it'll help you.
2. If the cat lives with other cats (like my story,) let them speak. If they live with humans, the humans won't understand them.
3. Try and have a book for reference. Mine was *Warriors* by Erin Hunter.